# Natural density of thickly syndetic set

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, natural-density

A syndetic set $S$
is a subset of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or integers $\mathbb{Z}$, having the property of "bounded gaps": that the sizes of the gaps in the sequence of natural numbers is bounded. That is to say, $S$ is a syndetic set, if there exist a positive integer $\ell$, such that for any $n$ , we have $\{n,n+1,\ldots,n+\ell\} \cap S$ is non-empty.
Set $T$ is thickly syndetic if
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^N T + i $$ is syndetic for each $N$, where $T + i = \{t + i \mid \forall t \in T\}$.
Is it true, that natural density $d(T) = 1?$ i.e.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|T \cap \{1, \ldots ,n\} |}{n} = 1 \text{ ?}$$

Comment: I don't think so. Form $T$ by choosing exactly one number from each set $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\dots$. The way that you choose a number is aperiodic, say following the Thue-Morse sequence (I just woke up).

Comment: Your set isn't thickly syndetic, as it can't contain any interval of length $3$, so $T \cap (T+1) \cap (T+2) = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 5):

No, the density might not exist, and the upper density (just $\limsup$ in your definition) could be arbitrarily small. Fix any $k$ and define $S = \{a \cdot k^{2b} + c \ : \ a,b \in \mathbb{N}, 0 \leq c < k^b\}$. $S$ is clearly thickly syndetic since intervals of length $k^b$ appear with gaps bounded from above by $k^{2b}$. And
for each $b$, the set of associated elements of $S$ has density $k^{-b}$, so the union $S$ has upper density bounded from above by $\sum_{b > 0} k^{-b} = \frac{1}{k-1}$.